# Explain me that difference in pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is element

```
var stickyBar=$('#sticky_bar');
```

Which has on load `position:fixed`, so I getting distance between `stickyBar` top and document top:

```
var initial=stickyBar.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
```

But, when I do this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
alert(initial+",  " + (stickyBar.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()))
});
```

These values are different: difference is 61px.

I can't get from where it comes from.

Comment: A jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) could be useful to see a working example of the problem.

Comment: I'm not seeing it:  http://jsfiddle.net/GbD37/

Comment: Yep, there is probably code outside that provided in the question that is affecting the outcome here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), jQuery's `offset()` does not account for margins, borders, or paddings. You should make sure you don't have any margins, borders, or paddings affecting the outcome.

You get the values of these margins, borders, and paddings by using

```
parseInt($("#sticky_bar").css("padding-top"))
```

and its variants. Then account for those values in your code.

Comment: so I should take in count margins and paddings manually, by adding some fixed values?

Comment: You can do so, but if you want a more robust solution you can use `parseInt($("#sticky_bar").css("padding-top"))` and variants to get those values and add them.

Comment: @Michal and to make it *faster*, use an bitwise-operator `$("#sticky_bar").css("paddingTop") | 0`...

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure through an inspector application that all values on the element (CSS Box Model) are 0. Went through Michal's fiddle and agree, the problem is somewhere on your end. User error.